# history.pushstate for changing url without page load not working

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to achieve changing content on page without changing url, using history.pushState but have been getting the following error

index.html:164 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///home/Desktop/abc/selected=box2' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///home/Desktop/abc/index.html'.
at HTMLAnchorElement. (file:///home/unfactory/Desktop/abc/index.html:164:17)

> **HTML Code**

```
<span style="float:right;"><a href="#" class="box" id='box1'>Contact Us</a></span>
<span style="float:right;"><a class='box' id='box2'>Asia-Pacific&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span>
<span style="float:right;"><a href="#top" class="box" id='box3'>Global&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span>
```

> **js Code**

```
function selectBox(id) {
    boxes.forEach(b => {
        b.classList.toggle('selected', b.id === id);
    })
}

let boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));
console.log(boxes);
boxes.forEach(b => {
    let id = b.id;
    console.log(id);
    b.addEventListener('click', e => {
        history.pushState({ id }, `Selected:${id}`, `./selected=${id}`)
        selectBox(id);
    })
})
```

Comment: Don’t expect stuff like this to work properly, when you are simply loading your HTML files from the file system. Setup up a local test server, so that you can access them properly via HTTP.

Comment: Is that a valid URL you're trying to push? Did you mean `file:///home/Desktop/abc/?selected=box2` instead? (Notice the query parameter)

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting that error and not an "Operation is not secure" error.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like `history.pushState` is deprecated and you need to use `history.push(url)`

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4049

Comment: That seems to be something React-specific. MDN is usually pretty good when it comes to mentioning when stuff is deprecated - but nothing on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState And https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History does not even mention any `push` method. And the HTML5 spec resp. the living standard don’t say anything about this being deprecated either, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate

Comment: if i try push its giving errors as Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function

Comment: `history.push` is for react-router. Not the web history api.